# timestamp operation in sqlalchemy

Tags: datetime, sqlalchemy, timestamp

I am trying to compare two timestamps, say `x` and `y`, where y should be current timestamp minus a certain number of seconds `s`, for example `y = sa.func.current_timestamp() - s`. But seems that `y` is not a timestamp. How can I convert that to timestamp?

example code

```py
def foo(x, y):
    # x is a timestamp, y is number of seconds
    y = sa.func.current_timestamp() - y
    return x > y
```

Comment: What is `type(y)`?

Comment: related: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672

Comment: @snakecharmerb y is `int`